# wirejs - New component instance for each depended component

Tags: javascript, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, wirejs

First: i'm new wirejs and its very possible i've missed something on the docs

On regular component declaration, like:

```
'Bnaya/App/TrackingService': {
    create: {
        module: 'Bnaya/App/TrackingService',
        args: []
    }
}
```

All of the components that will depend on that component using $ref, will get the same instance, so wire will be also kind of singleton mechanism (Which is good for me on most of the cases)

On some cases, i want that every dependent will get its own instance of the component, using the same component configurations.

```
'Bnaya/App/TrackingService': {
    create: {
        module: 'Bnaya/App/TrackingService',
        args: [],
        notASingleton: true
    }
}
```

I know how to get similar result using multiple components names or inline creating of instances, but that what i'm trying to avoid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to create multiple component instances in wire.js.  Depending on your needs you can see which one might work for you.

First, you can use the `create` factory to beget new instances from a prototype.  When you give `create` a function or constructor module, it will call them.  However, if you give `create` an existing object, it will use `Object.create` to beget a new instance, which you can then further configure as usual (e.g. using `properties`, `init`, advices, etc.).  Just keep in mind that it works exactly like `Object.create`, so prototype properties will be shared.

Second, you can use the [`wire` factory](https://github.com/cujojs/wire/blob/master/docs/components.md#wire) to achieve the effect you're after, though.  You just need to wrap the non-singleton in its own wire spec.  Here's a quick example:

```
thingThatNeedsATrackingService: {
    create: 'my/ThingThatNeedsATrackingService',
    properties: {
        foo: { wire: 'my/trackingServiceSpec' }
    }
},

otherThingThatNeedsATrackingService: {
    create: 'my/OtherThingThatNeedsATrackingService',
    properties: {
        foo: { wire: 'my/trackingServiceSpec' }
    }
},
//... more components
```

And then, in `my/trackingService.js`:

```
// Export the trackingService instance
$exports: { $ref: 'trackingService' },

trackingService: {
    create: {
        module: 'Bnaya/App/TrackingService',
        args: []
    }
},
//... more components if you need
```

That will inject a new instance of a `Bnaya/App/TrackingService` into each of the two things that needs one. The `$exports` allows you to export a specific component or components from a wire spec, much like CommonJS `exports`.

This approach has some nice benefits in that you can configure "private" components inside
`my/trackingService.js` and they will also be created as needed, but only the `trackingService` will be visible.  On the downside, it's sometimes a bit more work to separate a prototype component like this into its own wire spec.

An upcoming version of wire.js will support other types of component scopes, and so will make some cases easier.

Comment: My classes system in mostly backbone.
 is there a way to make the first method you've describe to work with it?
 I want to convince my team to use wire in a new project and the other method look more complex to grasp and a will require more changes to our current codebase.

arr i just can't format my comments properly here );
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, Backbone's Model and Collection aren't designed to work well with Object.create.  However, you can use the second technique (the wire factory) with Backbone quite effectively.  Another wire.js user created a project that shows it: https://github.com/pieterv/backbone-require-wire specifically, see: https://github.com/pieterv/backbone-require-wire/blob/master/js/todos/src/context/main.js#L54-L58